# DDD - Passing Aggregates?

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design

I'm working on a project, and desiging some aggregates. I have a User aggregate that has an address. The user must have a mailing and physical address, so there are some rules behind removing and adding addresses from the user.

Is it valid to have a User.UpdateAddress method, that accepts the following?

```
public ErrorOr<Updated> UpdateAddressDetails(Address address, AddressType type,
    string address1,
    string? address2,
    string city,
    Guid? stateId)
{
    var updateResult = CanUpdateAddress(address, type);
    if (updateResult.IsError) return updateResult.Errors;

    address.SetDetails(type, address1, address2, city, stateId);

    return Result.Updated;
}
```

Address is the address being updated, AddressType is the new address type that the address is being changed to - to verify that it can be updated to maintain at least a single mailing and single physical address type.

All the examples I see - they pass Id's around rather than the aggregates to another aggregate. But that wouldn't give me the required details to make some decisions. Is this a valid approach to calling methods on aggregates - by passing other aggregates?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a valid approach to calling methods on aggregates - by passing other aggregates?

Maybe.  Let's review

> An AGGREGATE is a cluster of associated objects that we treat as a unit for the purpose of data changes.  -- Eric Evans

Aggregate is a *lifecycle management* pattern (see Chapter 6).  Instead of manipulating a bunch of domain entities (see Chapter 5) directly, we instead delegate that work to an abstraction that ensures that the changes being made satisfy all of our domain rules.

(In practice, this usually means invoking a method on the "root entity" of an aggregate, and then letting that code decide where the work actually happens).

One of the important implications of the "treat as a unit" constraint is that all of the information in the aggregate is stored in one place - aka we can change the entire aggregate in a single atomic transaction.

Another way of expressing that idea: the aggregate has a single *lock*.

When you are introducing a second aggregate into the mix, we need to start thinking whether we are changing one aggregate (which one?) or both, which ones we need to lock, can the changes be committed atomically (what if the aggregates are stored in different databases?) and so on.

In short, adding the second aggregate into the mix increases the risk of introducing errors.  So we should, as a rule, avoid introducing a second aggregate into the mix unnecessarily.

A common alternative, when only a single aggregate is being modified, is to pass an unlocked copy of the information you need from the second aggregate, rather than the second aggregate itself.

---

In your example: if Address is an aggregate, and we are modifying Address without also modifying User, then we would normally organize the code differently: the method would be on Address, since that is what is being changed, and the information we need from User would be an unlocked copy (aka passing a Value, rather than passing an Aggregate).

(ie: part of the problem here may be that the update method is associated with the wrong aggregate).

Comment: The problem is the User must have a specific set of addresses. So we must know what addresses the user has when modifying the address itself. We can't remove an address or update it to a state that would let a user not have a specific set. Is this something that could possibly be fixed by moving this functionality to a domain service?

Comment: I wouldn't expect the domain service pattern to help here.  You might want to review your aggregate boundaries; it's common that when you have some must-be-true-every-nanosecond-of-every-day constraint on a set, the set _itself_ needs to be an aggregate.   Here, your collection of userId, addressId, addressType tuples might be an aggregate in and of itself, independent of the User and Address aggregates.